# Subtotal Calculation for Numerous Items - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
'Modular Variable Declaration Section
Dim mintOrdersPlacedToday As Integer
Dim msngTotalOfOrdersToday As Single
Dim msngShippingCost As Single = -1
Const csngSalesTaxRate As Single = 0.0625
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'Local Variable Declaration Section
    Dim sngShirtPrice As Single = 10
    Dim sngPremiumShirtPrice As Single = 20
    Dim sngHatsPrice As Single = 15
    Dim sngStickersPrice As Single = 5
    Dim sngSubTotal As Single
    Dim sngSalesTax As Single
    Dim sngOrderTotal As Single
    Dim intQuantity As Integer
    'Data Input Section
    If msngShippingCost = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a shipping method", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)    'Displays an error messsage when no shipping method is chosen
        Exit Sub 'Terminates the click event to allow shipping method to be chosen first
    End If

    Try     'Checks to see if the price is a valid number.
        'If it is, then it is assigned to the quantity variable, if not, error message and the event is halted.
        intQuantity = txtShirts.Text
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number of Shirts.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)    'Displays an error messsage when there is an invalid number
        txtShirts.Text = ""  'Clears the text box
        txtShirts.Focus()    'Puts the cursor in the price textbox
        Exit Sub    'Terminates the click event to allow valid input.
    End Try

    Try

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


    'Calculation Section
    sngSubTotal = intQuantity * sngShirtPrice  'Calculates the subtotal
    sngSalesTax = sngSubTotal * csngSalesTaxRate    'Calculates Sales Tax based on the sales tax rate constant
    sngOrderTotal = sngSubTotal + sngSalesTax + msngShippingCost 'Calculates total for the sale
    mintOrdersPlacedToday = mintOrdersPlacedToday + 1   'Calculates the number of orders placed today, adds one to the previous number
    msngTotalOfOrdersToday = msngTotalOfOrdersToday + sngOrderTotal 'Calculates the Total of all the orders placed today



    'Output section
    lblShowSubTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(sngSubTotal)  'Displays the Subtotal
    lblShowSalesTax.Text = FormatCurrency(sngSalesTax)  'Displays the Sales Tax
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(sngOrderTotal)  'Displays the Order Total
    lblShowOrdersPlacedToday.Text = mintOrdersPlacedToday   'Displays the Orders placed today
    lblShowTotalOfOrders.Text = FormatCurrency(msngTotalOfOrdersToday)  'Displays the Total of the Orders placed today
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = FormatCurrency(msngShippingCost)  'Displays the total of the shipping cost
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(" Are you sure you want to exit?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) 'Shows a messagebox for the user asking if they want to exit the program and gives them options.
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then   'States that if the user clicks Yes, the program will close
        Me.Close() 'Exits the program
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnClearCurentSale_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearCurentSale.Click
    'Clears the information from current sale and resets the form for the next sale
    radPickup.Checked = True 'Checks the Pickup radio button
    radPickup.Checked = False 'Unchecks the Pickup radio button
    btnCalculate.Enabled = True 'Enables the Calculate button
    msngShippingCost = -1   'Sets Shipping Cost to -1
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = "" 'Clears the Shipping Cost label
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the Order Total label
    lblShowSalesTax.Text = "" 'Clears the Sales Tax label
    lblShowSubTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the Sub Total label
    txtShirts.Text = "" 'Clears the Shirts text box
    txtShirts.Focus()   'Puts the cursor in the Shirts text box
End Sub

Private Sub radPickup_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radPickup.CheckedChanged
    msngShippingCost = 0    'Sets shipping cost as $0
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = "Free"   'Sets Shipping Cost label to show $0
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the Order Total label
End Sub

Private Sub radGround_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radGround.CheckedChanged
    msngShippingCost = 6.75 'Sets shipping cost as $6.75
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = FormatCurrency(6.75, 2)  'Sets Shipping Cost label to show $6.75
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the Order Total label
End Sub

Private Sub radTwoDay_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radTwoDay.CheckedChanged
    msngShippingCost = 12   'Sets shipping cost as $12
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = FormatCurrency(12, 2)    'Sets Shipping Cost label to show $12
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the Order Total label
End Sub

Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    'Clears the information for everything on the form
    txtShirts.Text = "" 'Clears the Shirts text box
    txtShirts.Focus()   'Puts the cursor in the Shirts text box
    lblShowSubTotal.Text = "" 'Clears the Sub Total label
    lblShowSalesTax.Text = "" 'Clears the Sales Tax label
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = "" 'Clears the Shipping Cost label
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = "" 'CLears the Order Total label
    lblShowOrdersPlacedToday.Text = "" 'Clears the Orders Placed Today label
    lblShowTotalOfOrders.Text = "" 'Clears the Total of Orders Today label
    mintOrdersPlacedToday = 0   'Resets the counter
    msngTotalOfOrdersToday = 0  'Resets the accumulator
End Sub
End Class
```

My question is: What would I do to make the calculation work for the user entering a quantity in numerous items textboxes? I'm stuck, please help.

There is a label on the left, then a textbox on the right. Label says "Shirts ($10.00)", textbox is where they enter the quantity of shirts they are buying. Same goes for the other 3 textboxes next to the other 3 labels, they enter the quantity of the item they are buying. Then they hit calculate after choosing shipping and it gives them a subtotal and all the rest. Don't bother with the shipping or anything else besides what it takes to get the subtotal. I need to make it so the user can enter a quantity in one, two, three, or all of the textboxes and hit calculate to get a proper subtotal. Sorry if I didn't explain correctly the first time. That is ALL I need, a way to get the calculation to work properly. Please help! :c

Answer (score 0):

**Edited answer in response to the fully edited Question:**

I've removed, and added some stuff. **Don't forget to add that shipment cost.**
And don't just copy paste this. Study it and see how it works, then adapt your code.

But without over-complicating things, the simplest way would be to sum each product separately, and then combine it.

See if this is what you're looking for.
*Note. After all, it's better if you just assign "0" in the textboxes instead to use Catch ex.

```
 Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'Local Variable Declaration Section
    Dim sngShirtPrice As Single = 10
    Dim sngPremiumShirtPrice As Single = 20
    Dim sngHatsPrice As Single = 15
    Dim sngStickersPrice As Single = 5
    Dim sngSalesTax As Single

    Dim sngOrderTotal As Single


    Dim StickersQuantity As Integer
    Dim sngStickersTotal As Single

    Dim ShirtsQuantity As Integer
    Dim sngShirtsTotal As Single

    Dim HatsQuantity As Integer
    Dim sngHatsTotal As Single


    If txtShirts.Text = Nothing Then

        txtShirts.Text = "0"

    End If

    If txtHats.Text = Nothing Then

        txtHats.Text = "0"

    End If

    If txtStickers.Text = Nothing Then

        txtStickers.Text = "0"

    End If

    ShirtsQuantity = txtShirts.Text
    HatsQuantity = txtHats.Text
    StickersQuantity = txtStickers.Text


    'Calculation Section
    sngShirtsTotal = ShirtsQuantity * sngShirtPrice
    sngHatsTotal = HatsQuantity * sngHatsPrice
    sngStickersTotal = StickersQuantity * sngStickersPrice

    Dim TTotal As Single

    TTotal = sngShirtsTotal + sngHatsTotal + sngStickersTotal


    sngSalesTax = TTotal * csngSalesTaxRate    'Calculates Sales Tax based on the sales tax rate constant


    sngOrderTotal = TTotal + sngSalesTax + msngShippingCost 'Calculates total for the sale
    mintOrdersPlacedToday = mintOrdersPlacedToday + 1   'Calculates the number of orders placed today, adds one to the previous number
    msngTotalOfOrdersToday = msngTotalOfOrdersToday + sngOrderTotal 'Calculates the Total of all the orders placed today



    'Output section
    lblShowSubTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(TTotal)  'Displays the Subtotal
    lblShowSalesTax.Text = FormatCurrency(sngSalesTax)  'Displays the Sales Tax
    lblShowOrderTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(sngOrderTotal)  'Displays the Order Total
    lblShowOrdersPlacedToday.Text = mintOrdersPlacedToday   'Displays the Orders placed today
    lblShowTotalOfOrders.Text = FormatCurrency(msngTotalOfOrdersToday)  'Displays the Total of the Orders placed today
    lblShowShippingCost.Text = FormatCurrency(msngShippingCost)  'Displays the total of the shipping cost
End Sub
```

Your code is kind of messy... I've only made the changes to the button click event.

Comment: You shouldn't use a Try-Catch for the calculations. Validating the input is a cleaner solution.

Comment: Taffs, thank you so much for helping out. I actually have a try catch, I didn't put in all my code, just the parts I was having trouble with, which was getting the subtotal to calculate correctly with numerous items. And have the user be able to put quantities in for more than one item at a time. By any chance can I get you to chat with me using Skype or something? Just text chat. Until I get this sorted out completely? I would be so grateful.

Comment: Also, I forgot to put that I have `dim intQuantity as Integer` defined at the top as well.

Comment: I've updated my response. I too think that simply assinging "0" to the textbox instead of catching ex is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial *ordering system*, which greatly simplifies the calculation as you simply add/remove products to the order.

**Example:**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim beers = new ProductOrder(New BeerProduct, 20)
        Dim tacos = new ProductOrder(New TacosProduct, 100)
        Dim order As New Order
        order.Products.Add(beers)
        order.Products.Add(tacos)

        Dim totalForBeers = beers.Total
        Dim totalForTacos = tacos.Total
        Dim grandTotal = order.GrandTotal
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Classes powering all this:**

A product that has a price:

```
Public MustInherit Class Product
    MustOverride ReadOnly Property Price() As Decimal
End Class
```

Some products:

```
Public Class BeerProduct
    Inherits  Product

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Price() As Decimal
        Get
            Return 10.0D
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class TacosProduct
    Inherits  Product

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Price() As Decimal
        Get
            Return 5.0D
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The order-related types:

```
Public Class ProductOrder
    Property Product() As Product
    Property Quantity() As Integer

    ReadOnly Property Total As Decimal
        Get
            Return Product.Price*Quantity
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Sub New(ByVal product As Product, ByVal quantity As Integer)
        Me.Product = product
        Me.Quantity = quantity
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Order
    Private ReadOnly _products As List(Of ProductOrder)

    Public Sub New()
        _products = New List(Of ProductOrder)()
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property Products() As List(Of ProductOrder)
        Get
            return _products
        End Get
    End Property

    ReadOnly Property GrandTotal() As Decimal
        Get
            Return Products.Sum(Function (x) x.Total)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

**TODO**

- present this in a friendly manner such as using a `DataGrid`
- allow the user to add a `Product` using a `ComboBox` or whatever
- etc ...

Note that I haven't addressed those aspects since you haven't told under what framework you are using (WPF or Forms).

Good luck !

Comment: You've lost me there.
I'm using a form.
I'm going to post the entire code in a second. Check back for an edit to the post.